# python webdriver run execute_script error:Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I am using selenium-python bindings to do some basic browser testing. I need to click an element, which is invisible by default.So I want make the invisible element visible,I have tried to use `execute_script()`monthod to make it visible by using the following code.However the JS code `document.getElementsByClassName("bdpfmenu")[0].style.display="block";` run successfully within Console,but it occurs error massages when I use `execute_script()`with python

```
js = 'document.getElementsByClassName("bdpfmenu")[0].style.display="block";'
driver.execute_script(js)
```

and the error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

Comment: Share `HTML` for the same. There might be multiple elements with class name `"bdpfmenu"`. You might need to use more specific selector

Answer (score 0):

You can get the style attribute and compare.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("bdpfmenu")[0].getAttribute("style")
```